# FFmpeg drawbox and ZMQ b'38 Function not implemented'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, stream, zeromq

I am trying to dynamically control the size and position of a box on a rtsp stream, exposed by ffmpeg. I found a potential solution that is based on zmq. I have recompiled ffmpeg with zmq support and run the stream with the command

```
ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 1000000 -i "rtsp://<STREAM_ADDR>" -pix_fmt bgra -filter_complex zmq,drawbox=x=10:y=10:w=50:h=50:c=red -f fbdev /dev/fb0
```

Then I'm trying to send update with python3 script from ffmpeg repo tools (I modified it to adjust python3)

```py
import sys, zmq, cmd

class LavfiCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = 'lavfi> '

    def __init__(self, bind_address):
        context = zmq.Context()
        self.requester = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
        self.requester.connect(bind_address)
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)

    def onecmd(self, cmd):
        if cmd == 'EOF':
            sys.exit(0)
        print('Sending command:[%s]' % cmd)
        self.requester.send_string(cmd)
        message = self.requester.recv()
        print('Received reply:[%s]' % message)

try:
    bind_address = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else "tcp://localhost:1235"
    LavfiCmd(bind_address).cmdloop('FFmpeg libavfilter interactive shell')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I try to send

```
Parsed_drawbox_1 reinit x=40
```

or

```
Parsed_drawbox_1 x 40
```

But still got `Received reply:[b'38 Function not implemented']` from script.
When I set verbose on ffmpeg I can see

```
[Parsed_zmq_0 @ 0x5594e2d3b0] Processing command #8 target:Parsed_drawbox_1 command:reinit arg:w=40
[Parsed_zmq_0 @ 0x5594e2d3b0] Sending command reply for command #8:
38 Function not implemented
```

Does anyone have an idea what can cause it, or how to better debug it?

Thanks

Comment: it seems `FFmpeg` doesn't know this command `Parsed_drawbox_1` - maybe you have to recompile with another module, or maybe it has to be different command. Where did you find `Parsed_drawbox_1`? Do you have link to documentation? Put it in question, not in comments.

Comment: ffmpeg ver has to be >= 4.3

Comment: Thanks @Gyan. That was an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Gyran I was able to resolve it.

My FFmpeg version was 4.2.2 so I updated it to 4.3.1.

Command should be just e.g.

```
Parsed_drawbox_1 x 300
```